# CakePHP v2.x - More then one set of config files

Tags: cakephp, config

I have "inherited" legacy CakePHP application which should be now deployed to multiply clients. I have search through the [documentation for the version 2.x](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/index.html), but I was unable to find the following:

How can I easily store the different Config files for different clients? The reason is simple, each client will have different database details, different email setup ...

Should I have a default folder and for the other make a duplicate folder named Config_another_client_name folder and inside have a copy of those files? Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: Are you running all of these deployments on one server from a single copy of the code?

Comment: Yes, code will contain parameters for each client. Logo for example, site title...but code will be the same for all clients.

Comment: What you might want to do, then, is find where `app_local` gets loaded, and instead (or in addition) load a client-specific config file that contains the particulars that change. Alternately, assuming that they're all running on their own domain or subdomain, you could put those things into the environment through web server configuration, and read them from there.